# PHP: How to get characters length of specific associative array key value

Tags: php, arrays

i need get characters length of "fsdfsdf". Who can help me? :)

```
$array = array(
    'Firstname' => $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['Firstname']),
    'Lastname' => $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['Lastname']),
    'Phone' => $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['Phone']),
    'Email' => $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['Email'])
);
```

print_r($array):

```
Array
(
    [Firstname] => fsdfsdf
    [Lastname] => 
    [Phone] => 
    [Email] =>
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$char_length = strlen($array['Firstname']);
```

Comment: was very easy, because i was tried get it with $array->Firstname, i dont know why :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$length =   strlen($array[Firstname]);
echo $length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps you,

```
 echo strlen(trim($array['Firstname']));
```